# Names of textual chord notation systems

Tags: chords, notation, terminology

I use three types of textual chord notation. For example in the key of C:

1. [Nashville number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashville_number_system): 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2. C Dm Em F G Am Bdim
3. I ii iii IV V vi viiØ *or* I IIm IIIm IV V VIm VIIØ

What do you call chord notations #2 and #3?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(music)#Notation. Marco notation is close to number 2 but not sure if it has a proper name other than "symbols"

Answer (score 4):

Notation 2, as far as I'm concerned, is just labeling the chord roots and qualities. But if you really want a name, I'd probably go with **lead-sheet notation**. Some lead sheets use `-` to indicate minor, and there are particular rules for notating seventh chords.

Notation 3 is, without a doubt, **Roman numeral notation**. There are traditions that use all capital Roman numerals (I, II, III, etc.), but the prevailing trend seems to be what you've done, with uppercase and lowercase showing chord quality.

Answer (score 3):

2 is just **chord symbols**. They don't really need a name outside of that since they just represent a generic harmonic idea on a given note. This is sometimes used as the basis of Macro analysis, but I would never call them macro symbols.

3 is **Roman Numeral Analysis** where you just refer to the symbols as **Roman Numerals**. I want to reflect the analysis portion of the name since that's a big part of the and where you'll get the most use out of the system. Especially when you get into things like secondary chords and modulation. I *can* be used outside of a functional context like saying I II V I, instead of I V/V V I. The first which is non functional may make more sense for transposing chords, but the second functional ways better show what is happening.